# Present view over parent View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a VC called PagingViewController (its a UIViewController with a paging UIScrollView) and this has 3 child VC’s, let’s called them VC-1, VC-2, and VC-3.

I am doing networking calls inside of the child VC-1 and during this I want to cover everything on screen including the parent PagingViewController.
How would I do this in a way that doesn't violate MVC architecture? Also should I present a UIView or a UIViewController for the loading screen to cover the parent?

I have tried using the `UIWindow` but this seems like a hack but not sure if it is

### Update 1

Besides the `UIWindow` that I mentioned above, another way to cover the parent's screen from the child is to do: `self.parent.view.addSubview(myCustomView)`. My concern is that the child is reaching into the parent's view and adding a view to it. This to me seems like its violating something (I could be wrong)

Comment: You are describing a perfectly ordinary fullscreen presented view controller. What's the problem?

Comment: @matt I updated my question. Notice how I mention that the child is reaching into the parent to add a view. In the other example, I would be reaching for the UIWindow which also seems wrong to me. (Or maybe both of these approaches are perfectly ok with MVC)

Comment: If I present a VC instead of a just a UIView, then I see this as being simple, because then you just do `present.. (view controller)`.. but with a UIView, its hard to show something to cover your parents views as well

Comment: "but with a UIView, its hard to show something to cover your parents views as well" The issue is that you cannot interleave views from different view controllers. But the presented view controller's view _will_ cover everything, which is what you want, so why isn't that the solution?

Comment: @matt My parent, in this case `PagingViewController`, has a custom toolbar that is not covered if all I do is `self.view.addSubview` inside the child (the child being VC-1). So basically everything is covered from the parent, except that custom toolbar. What's worse is that since you can scroll inside of `PagingViewController` due to the paging UIScrollView, the view that is added does not block the scrolling since it is added just to its view hierarchy. Hopefully I explained this clearly

Comment: Maybe the loading screen should be ViewController, idk

Comment: You haven't explained anything. A fullscreen presented view controller's view will cover everything, no user interaction will be possible with anything behind it, problem solved, totally standard, way better than the illegal second window Fahim is proposing.

Comment: Um yeah so use a view controller, not a uiview to be presented from the childVC. What I had as my loading screen this entire time was a uiview - I'll change that to be a view controller

Answer (score 1):

If the UIWindow approach works for you, I'd say go with it :) But you should be able to display a view from either the child VC-1 or the parent view (which would be the view of the PagingViewController - if it displays any UI) to cover the full area of the view too. Personally, I'd say either approach is fine depending on what you want to do.

Comment: I see thanks! What if I do something like `self.parent?.view.addSubview(myCustomView)`, so `self` in this case is VC-1, the child view controller. `parent` is the `PagingViewController`. Is this bad architecture - like does it go against MVC?

Comment: I am probably not the right person to ask if you are interested in "standards" :) I don't try to follow every rule or standard. I code based on what would work for my current situation as long as it doesn't create unmaintainable code or create other issues that would make the app a bad app. In this case, using a sub-view as you suggested, would probably be easier than using a UIWindow and generally, that's what I'd go for :)

Comment: Sure : ) I guess I am thinking about the standards in a way - what you say does make sense like if its working why not and this is maintainable. I'm going to see how this plays out and do more research on if it violates mvc in any way

Comment: Personally, I don't think there would be any MVC issues since you are showing a view from within another view. But I don't keep up with all the intricacies of MVC design. So I might be wrong :)

Also, if you think the answer helped you, could you please mark it "correct"? (Unless of course, you don't think it is ... :D)

Comment: Kk, I just upvoted it as it us super helpful : ) Srry if I wasn't;t super clear in question about going with standard architecture, hopefully someone will chime in on that -- If not then ill mark this as correct : )

Comment: Actually, thinking about MVC, I guess you really need to have the controller handle the displaying of a new view. So you'd need to send out a notification (for instance) and then have the parent view controller (the `PagingViewController` in your case) handle the showing of the overlay view.